# Should I put dusted roaches back in the feeder box

Tags: feeding, reptiles, bearded-dragon

I have a baby bearded dragon (3 months+/-) I dust her live food - dubia roaches) each day. Should I put the dusted roaches back into the feeder box even though they might get dusted again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is perfectly OK, they won't go bad.

The only issue is if their substrate is moist then you can get mold from the powder.